# ngSticky directive for angular with tables

Tags: angularjs, ngsticky

I am using the ngSticky directive (https://github.com/d-oliveros/ngSticky) because I want to fix the thead of my table when offset=50. But the width of the thead is changed when I get the offser=50. This is the correct vision of my table:

[image]

And this is what I get:

[image]

th and tr have different width!

My code for the table is:

```
 <div class="table-responsive">           
   <table class="table table-condensed persist-area">
     <thead sticky offset="50">                      
       <tr class="info">
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use the directive cmelo.angularSticky: https://github.com/cmelo/angular-sticky
It works perfectly for me.

Install with bower: bower install cmelo-angular-sticky

Include JS file:

```
<script src="../bower_components/cmelo-angular-sticky/cmelo-sticky.js"></script>
```

Add module dependency:

```
angular.module('Destinator', ['cmelo.angularSticky'])
```

Add cmelo-sticky to the body:

```
<body cmelo-sticky>
```

Add cmelo-sticky-top to thead:

```
<thead cmelo-sticky-top>
```